# Trying to implement MAUI Swipe to change Image

Tags: swipe, maui

I'm creating a simple page to change the image by swiping. Swipe left gives the next image and swipe right the previous. Unfortunately the swipe events don't  trigger.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Alm.MainPage">
    
    <SwipeView SwipeEnded="SwipeView_SwipeEnded" Threshold="200">
        <SwipeItemView>             
        <Image >
            <Image.Source>
                <UriImageSource x:Name="Sorsa" Uri="https://someurl.com/someimage.jpg"></UriImageSource>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
        </SwipeItemView>
    </SwipeView>
 
</ContentPage>
```

And the event is:

```cs
private void SwipeView_SwipeChanging(object sender, SwipeChangingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.SwipeDirection == SwipeDirection.Left)
        Sorsa.Uri = HaeEdellinen();
    if (e.SwipeDirection == SwipeDirection.Right)
        Sorsa.Uri = HaeSeuraava();
}
```

but it never fires.

Comment: Your event handler is called `SwipeView_SwipeChanging` but in your XAML, you're using `SwipeView_SwipeEnded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly add the `Swipe GestureRecognizer` to the **image** and detect the swipe direction: `Left` or `Right` to change the source for the image. Here's the code snippet below for your reference:

**Xaml:**

```
<Image x:Name="img" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" Source="logo.png" > 
         <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                 <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" 
                                         Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Left"/>


                 <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" 
                                         Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Right"/>

         </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_Left(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e) 
{
    img.Source = "logo.png";
}

private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_Right(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
{
    img.Source = "uk.jpg";
}
```